# Error in as.xts

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo, quantmod

I have an xts object, `close` (with a `POSIXct` index). It gives this error when I run the *quantmod* command `specifyModel(close[,1] ~ close[,2])`:

```
 Error in UseMethod("as.xts") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.xts' applied to an object of class "function".

                     ALBK ANDHRABANK AXISBANK BANKBARODA
2007-01-02 10:01:00 90.89      87.33   468.55     243.95
2007-01-02 10:02:00 90.80      86.92   467.75     243.70
2007-01-02 10:03:00 90.45      86.77   468.65     243.60
2007-01-02 10:04:00 90.31      86.94   468.32     243.95
2007-01-02 10:05:00 90.27      87.05   468.60     244.00
2007-01-02 10:06:00 90.23      87.00   468.00     243.65
2007-01-02 10:07:00 90.24      86.89   467.50     243.60
2007-01-02 10:08:00 89.99      86.77   467.05     243.00
2007-01-02 10:09:00 90.05      86.80   467.40     243.00
2007-01-02 10:10:00 90.20      87.00   467.00     243.00
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It's getting confused because `close` is the name of a base R function.  (probably a bug, but I'm not sure how widely used `specifyModel` is)

```
> close <- getSymbols("SPY", src="yahoo", auto.assign=FALSE)
> specifyModel(close[, 1] ~ close[, 2])
Error in UseMethod("as.xts") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.xts' applied to an object of class "function"
```

Fix by renaming your xts object

```
> dat <- close
> specifyModel(dat[, 1] ~ dat[, 2])

quantmod object:        Build date:   

Model Specified: 
     dat[, 1] ~ dat[, 2] 

Model Target:  [ dat 0.1         Product:  dat 
Model Inputs:   

Fitted Model: 

    None Fitted
>
```

Comment: Let us say I have 4 columns in dat <- close and want to use specifyModel(dat[,1] ~ dat[,2] + dat[,3] + dat[,4] ). It should take first column on one side of formula and remaining columns on the other side of the formula. I try with specifyModel(dat[,1] ~ . ) which does not work. Any idea on this.

Comment: AFAICT, that's not how `specifyModel` is intended to be used.  But, I haven't seen it used anywhere other than in the sole example -- have you?

Comment: In fact, notice that although my answer avoids the error you had, it doesn't actually do anything useful (see the "None Fitted" part?).  I think the idea is that it downloads data with getSymbols and uses that directly.  So, instead of `specifyModel(dat[, 1] ~ dat[, 2])` it should be something like `specifyModel(SPY ~ QQQ)` where `SPY` and `QQQ` are either objects in your `.GlobalEnv` or things that `getSymbols` can download.  Like I said, I don't think this function is used much.

Comment: I have a data frame dat with many columns and each column represent data for one specific company. Formula variable in the specifyModel has to be updated automatically if the number of columns in dat changes. formula  = dat[,1] ~ dat[,2]. it may also be like formula  = dat[,1] ~ dat[,2] + dat[,3] + dat[,4]. To change the formula variable in loop, I can;t use predefind names in specificModel.